# Is there a way to use file shortcuts with Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have a main `src` folder where I keep all the `.cpp` files so I can easily compile with a simple `Makefile`. But, if I want to test a specific functionality, I don't want to clutter the main folder with tests, so I seperated it into a `test` folder. Now, I still use a `Makefile` so I can keep the same compiler flags, etc. But, I don't want to simply copy over the files I want to test because they may be unsynced with the main files without me noticing. Is there a way to solve this problem? I thought of using shortcuts to the actual file in the `test` folder but `Makefile` complains that there is `no rule to make target ... needed by all. Stop'. I am on Windows.

Comment: To answer your direct question no, there is no way to use Windows shortcuts with make.  However, it's very likely that you can get what you want without bothering with them at all.  Unfortunately the description above is not sufficient for us to help with that: why do you want to create shortcuts?  Why not just use the path to the test files in your makefile?  Why do you have to "copy over the files"?  I don't really understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Windows supports [junctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions#junctions). You can create it from command line, with [`mklink`](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) command.